Resolution lower bound for pigeonhole principle when placement clauses are shortened
Consider the standard CNF encoding of pigeonhole principle $PHP_{n}^{n+1}$:
$$ \text{Placement clauses: } x_{i,1} \lor x_{i,2} \lor \cdots \lor x_{i,n} \forall i \in [n+1] $$
$$ \text{Collision clauses: } \neg x_{i_1, j} \lor \neg x_{i_2, j} \forall i_1, i_2 \in [n+1], i_1 \neq i_2, j \in [n] $$
To prove lower bounds against $PHP_n^{n+1}$ one defines the measure $\mu(C)$ for each clause $C$ as $\mu(C) = | \{ i | \text{ there exists an }i\text{ critical assignment falsifying }C\}|$ (where an $i$-critical assignment is an assignment which doesn't place pigeon $i$ and places remaining pigeons inductively). Then, one notes that $\mu(\phi)=n+1$,$\mu(\text{axiom}) \leq 1$ and $\mu$ is subadditive which allows us to locate a clause $C$ with $\mu(C) \in [n/3, 2n/3]$. Then we argue about the clause $C$.
My question: suppose we want to make the placement clause short for certain reasons - we do that the standard way by using auxiliary variables:
$$ x_{i,1} \lor x_{i,2} \lor \cdots \lor x_{i,n} \rightarrow( x_{i,1} \lor Z_{i,2} ) \land (\neg Z_{i,2} \lor x_{i,2} \lor  Z_{i,3}) \land \cdots \land (\neg Z_{i,n} \lor x_{i,n})$$
How do we argue about lower bounds for this formula? The issue is that $\mu$ for some of the axioms can be extremely large - e.g. $\mu (\neg Z_{i,2} \lor x_{i,2} \lor Z_{i,3}) = n+1$, so it's not clear how we can locate a clause with medium $\mu$
